# Mailer Callback with resque

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, resque

I use Resque Mailer with Rails 3's ActionMailer to send emails asynchronously. Is there a way to add callback to my ActionMailer class after a mail has been sent?

Comment: @RubyFanatic I thing ActiveSupport::Notification see if that can help

Comment: https://github.com/kelyar/mailer_callbacks/issues/1 was for rails 2.x but I'm hoping to find a 3.x solution as well